# gorm transaction: reflect: Field index out of range

Tags: go, go-gorm

Im having trouble creating a transaction using golang gorm orm. I am getting field index out of range error. Cant seem to understand the problem here. I am running the transaction in [manual mode](https://gorm.io/docs/transactions.html#Control-the-transaction-manually).

in go.mod file

*gorm.io/driver/mysql v1.3.6 // indirect*

*gorm.io/gorm v1.23.8 //indirect*

My Models are

```
type Company struct {
    ID        uint64         `json:"id"`
    Name      string         `gorm:"size:255;not null" json:"name"`
    OwnerID   uint64         `gorm:"not null" json:"owner_id"`
    CreatedAt *time.Time     `gorm:"autoCreateTime" json:"created_at,omitempty"`
    UpdatedAt *time.Time     `gorm:"autoUpdateTime" json:"updated_at,omitempty"`
}

type CompanyUser struct {
    ID        uint64     `json:"id"`
    UserID    uint64     `gorm:"not null" json:"user_id"`
    CompanyID uint64     `gorm:"not null" json:"company_id"`
    CreatedAt *time.Time `gorm:"autoCreateTime" json:"created_at,omitempty"`
    UpdatedAt *time.Time `gorm:"autoUpdateTime" json:"updated_at,omitempty"`
}
```

now in my code:

```
    ownerID := 1 

    db := GetDB() //returns *gorm.DB
    tx := db.Begin()
    
    company := &models.Company{
            OwnerID: ownerID,
            Name:    "Lorem Ipsum",
          }
    
    tx = tx.Create(company)
    if tx.Error != nil {
            tx.Rollback()
            return tx.Error
        }

    fmt.Println(company.ID) //prints the id perfectly

    company_user := &models.CompanyUser{
            UserID:    ownerID,
            CompanyID: company.ID,
        }
    tx = tx.Create(company_user) // <= this line panics
    if tx.Error != nil {
            tx.Rollback()
            return tx.Error
        }
    
   result := tx.Commit()
   if result.Error != nil {
           tx.Rollback()  
        return tx.Error
       }
```

The weird part is if i duplicate this line     `tx = tx.Create(company)` multiple times inside this transaction and comment out the     `tx = tx.Create(company_user)` line, then the transaction works perfectly. It inserts multiple company model without any complain.

If I do the same with only `tx = tx.Create(company_user)` line (with hard coded value), it is successful in creating multiple company_user model without any complain.

But when I am using both `tx = tx.Create(company)` and `tx = tx.Create(company_user)` together inside this transaction, it gives error: **reflect: Field index out of range**

gorm config used while initializing db connection:

```
&gorm.Config{
        SkipDefaultTransaction: true,
        PrepareStmt:            true,
    }
```

Comment: using [this approach](https://gorm.io/docs/transactions.html#Transaction) works perfectly though. But manual one fails

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
rs := tx.Create(company)
if rs.Error != nil {
        tx.Rollback()
        return tx.Error
    }
rs = tx.Create(company_user) // <= this line panics
if rs.Error != nil {
        tx.Rollback()
        return tx.Error
    }
```

just don't assign value of `tx.Create()` to `tx`